# Download file from one stream and save it to zip in another stream without putting all data in memory

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm a complete beginner to dealing with streams or anything like this, so if you see anything obviously wrong... that's why. I have some files stored on azure. I need to take the files, zip them up, and return the zip.

I've tested this with a 1GB file, and although it works, it ends up using 2.5GB of memory. Memory usage spikes between when the last line starts and completes. I'm not sure why this is loading everything in memory, so I'm not quite sure what i'm supposed to do to prevent that from happening. What's the correct way to do it? The only thing I can think of is to specify buffer sizes somewhere, but everywhere i've seen where it's possible has a small default.

```
FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream("test.zip", FileMode.Create);
ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update, true);
ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = archive.CreateEntry("entryName", CompressionLevel.Optimal);

// ... some azure code
file = await dir.GetFileReference(fileName);
fileContents = await file.OpenReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

await fileContents.CopyToAsync(zipEntry.Open()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: The memory usage of a .NET Application can be highly misleading. This is due to the Garbage Collector prefering not to run before application closure if possible. You could for testing purposes add a "GC.Collect()" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx) to the end of your code. This might even one of the rare cases where keeping such a call in the code could be helpfull for Release builds (normally it you should not have such a call in your code).

Comment: As it was to long for the first post, here some recommended reading to fully understand how memory management works, how to measure it, etc: http://www.itwriting.com/dotnetmem.php https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/286d8c7f-87ca-46b9-9608-2b559d7dc79f/garbage-collection-pros-and-limits?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I'm looking at the built in diagnostic tools in visual studio for the memory usage if that matters. I see the memory spike between when the last line starts and completes. If I put the GC.collect() at the end, the memory will have already spiked, unless i'm misunderstanding.

Comment: The GC will allocate memory. But it will not de-allocate memory ever, unless it is forced too (GC.Collect, Danger of OOM) or you close the application. This especially applies to any temporary variables you (or code you call) might use. As a result sometimes you can have really odd spikes, when not much memory is actually in use - just a lot of stuff that run out of scope taht is not cleaned up. The worst example is propably string connacting in a loop (so problematic, there is a extra class for this operation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Comment: I see. So how do I see how much memory this actually uses? This will eventually be a webservice, and I need to make sure that a single user with a huge file doesn't take all the memory and cause issues.

Comment: I don't think it is a normal case. 2.5GB of memory just for stream copy is too much... Seems like zipEntry holds the whole content in memory before writing to disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create archive as

```
ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
```

Your memory consumption will drop to minimal (In my test case it dropped from 900M to 36M)...

Seems like problem is related with *ZipArchiveMode.Update*

```
void Zip(IEnumerable<string> files, Stream inputStream)
{
    using (var zip = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(inputStream, System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (var file in files.Select(f => new FileInfo(f)))
        {
            var entry = zip.CreateEntry(file.Name, System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Fastest);
            using (var s = entry.Open())
            {
                using (var f = File.Open(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    f.CopyTo(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple files I need to add to the zip, so I think I need update.

Comment: No, you can add many files with *Create*. Just you can not delete and add at the same time. Don't guess... try and see